# PHP elseif when value 0

Tags: php, if-statement

i have a problem with the following code.
If the next 3qty, 4qty or 5qty is 0, i cant get my actual value.
I need something like: if 3qty = 0 -> ignore

```
if($volume >= $1qty && $volume < $2qty)
{
$actual = $one;
}
elseif($volume >= $2qty && $volume < $3qty)
{
$actual = $two;
}
elseif($volume >= $3qty && $volume < $4qty)
{
$actual = $three;
}
elseif($volume >= $4qty && $volume < $5qty)
{
$actual = $four;
}
elseif($volume >= $5qty)
{
$actual = $five;
}
```

i hope someone can help me, i cant get a solution for my problem by my self :/

Comment: Please elaborate. E.g. sample data and the expected results would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if($1qty != 0){
 if($volume >= $1qty && $volume < $2qty){
  $actual = $one;
 }
 elseif($volume >= $2qty && $volume < $3qty){
  $actual = $two;
 }
 elseif($volume >= $3qty && $volume < $4qty){
  $actual = $three;
 }
 elseif($volume >= $4qty && $volume < $5qty){
  $actual = $four;
 }
 elseif($volume >= $5qty){
  $actual = $five;
 };
}
```

at the beginning I'm validating that is, if it is not, continue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( $2qty>0 && $3qty>0 && $4qty>0 && $5qty>0 ) {
    if( $volume>=$1qty && $volume<$2qty ) {
        $actual = $one;
    } else if( $volume>=$2qty && $volume<$3qty ) {
        $actual = $two;
    } else if( $volume>=$3qty && $volume<$4qty ) {
        $actual = $three;
    } else if( $volume>=$4qty && $volume<$5qty ) {
        $actual = $four;
    } else if( $volume>=$5qty ) {
        $actual = $five;
    } else {
        $actual = false;
    }
} else {
    $actual = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following work finde:

```
if($1qty != 0 && $2qty != 0 && $3qty == 0 && $4qty == 0 && $5qty == 0){
if($volume >= $1qty && $volume < $2qty)
{
$actual = $one;
}
elseif($volume >= $2qty)
{
$actual = $two;
}
elseif($1qty != 0 && $2qty != 0 && $3qty != 0 && $4qty == 0 && $5qty == 0){
if($volume >= $1qty && $volume < $2qty)
{
$actual = $one;
}
elseif($volume >= $2qty && $volume < $3qty)
{
$actual = $two;
}
elseif($volume >= $3qty)
{
$actual = $three;
}
```

and so on.